# What is the support duration or end of life for log4j1.x bridge jar. How long is the bridge library supported by apache?

Tags: java, log4j2, end-of-life

For migrating Log4j 1.x to 2.x in java applications that  still using Log4j 1.x API OR the application depends on a library which depends on the Log 1.x API. Apache recommends using the bridge jar.

- log4j-api.jar
- log4j-core.jar
- log4j-1.2-api.jar (**Log4j 1.x bridge jar**)

I am using the bridge since some 3rd party vendor chose not to upgrade to log4j2.x their jars that we use.

(could'nt find the information on Apache site or a way to ask them)
**Can some one share light on :**
*how long with the bridge library be supported?*
*what would happen if the support for the bridge library is discontinued?*

Answer (score 0):

There are **no** plans to deprecate `log4j-1.2-api` in the near future.

The bridge will still be supported in the upcoming 3.x series, which means that it will surely be supported until 4.x comes up. Basically we are talking about decades.

On the other hand the Log4j2 API is a strict superset of the Log4j 1.x (the "API" part), so it is relatively easy to weave classes using Log4j 1.x to use Log4j2 directly. A tool similar to [Tomcat migration tool](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi) should not be too hard to write.